# Adding private chat functionality to simple twisted chat server

Tags: python-2.7, chat, twisted

I am trying to learn twisted library from its documentation. I've created a simple chat server that allows users to public chat. However, I wonder if I can add private chat functionality to that. I am looking for your ideas. Thanks.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Chat(LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self,users):
        self.users = users
        self.name = None
        self.state = "GETNAME"

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("What's your name?")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.users.has_key(self.name):
            del self.users[self.name]

    def lineReceived(self,line):
        if self.state == "GETNAME":
            self.handle_GETNAME(line)
        else:
            self.handle_CHAT(line)

    def handle_GETNAME(self,name):
        if self.users.has_key(name):
            self.sendLine("Name taken, please choose another.")
            return
        self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name))
        self.name = name
        self.users[name] = self
        self.state = "CHAT"

    def handle_CHAT(self,msg):
        msg = "<%s> %s" % (self.name,msg)
        for name,protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if protocol != self:
                protocol.sendLine(msg)

class ChatFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {}
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Chat(self.users)

reactor.listenTCP(8123,ChatFactory())  #@UndefinedVariable
reactor.run() #@UndefinedVariable
```

Comment: What is "private chat"?  What problem are you encountering implementing it?

Comment: This code works for multiple clients. When somebody connected to server and writes something, all the clients can see that. However I need a feature that allows client to chat with only one other client, not all. Therefore, I mean "private chat"

Comment: Okay.  And what problem are you encountering implementing that?  In other words, treat stackoverflow as a place to ask questions about things you're having trouble with in order to learn how to not have trouble with them.  Don't treat it as a place to ask people to implement your program for you (which is how your question *reads* at the moment, even if that wasn't your intent).

Comment: I did not treat stackoverflow like that. If you carefully look at the code I've posted, you can easily see that it is just a little bit change in the for loop in handle_CHAT method, which I found today and post it as a solution in a minute.

Comment: As I said, I don't know what your *intent* was.  I only know what your question looks like to me, and it looks like what I described.  I tried to suggest ways you could change your question to make it more easily answered.  I'm sorry if you don't like those suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured it out by changing the for loop in handle_CHAT. As I want the program to send the message to the specific user, a "talkwith" string can be added to the class and this string can hold that specific user's name. Then this change turns the program from public to private chatting.

```
msg = "<%s> %s" % (self.name,msg)
            for name,protocol in self.users.iteritems():
                if name == self.talkwith:
                    protocol.sendLine(msg)
```